# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-8, windows-server-2016

We were running Windows Server 2008 R2 and upgraded to 2016 and since then our applications have stopped running. ASP.NET Web Forms is still working and only MVC seems to have stopped running.

They were all thrwoing HTTP 503 error and after repaiting IIS URL Rewrite Module 2, they have started throwing the following error:

Server Error in '/Mail' Application.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.



WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



Stack Trace: 



[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +0
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +194
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +80
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +70
```

`System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +18`

`System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +444
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157`

`Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve by doing two things:

1. Repairing the IIS URL Rewrite Module
2. Uninstalling Microsoft Monitoring Agent which contains the assembly that MVC application is complaining about.